# Install test app on surface hub by creating provisioning package

Tags: uwp, appx, surface-hub

I want to install my test app on surface pro 4. But I dont want to publish it on store. For that first I have created an **`app package`** by clicking on **Store->Create App Packages**. And Selected **No** in the first dialog asking if you want to build packages to upload to the Windows Store.The package is created successfully. 
And then I have imported the certificate as described below.

```
Opened the security certificate for the appx package, and selected Install Certificate.
On the Certificate Import Wizard, selected Local Machine.
Imported the certificate to the **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** folder.
```

After that I started to create the `provisioning package` by using windows configuration designer (advanced provisioning). I refered [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/provisioning-packages-for-surface-hub) link for it. But I cant add the certificate path and already generated appxbundle to it. Browse option is not dispalying those files. What should be the reason for it?
I have choosen ClientCertificates as in the link. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

A thing you might be able to is to use the remote machine debugging option of Visual studio to install it on your surface through an internet connection.

All UWP apps are firstly installed before they are debugged so this might be the fastest and smartest solution.

Also, don't bother too much with certifications, they are not needed, they are hardly needed even when you upload to store.

Finally another solution is to just upload to the store but make it invisible to users, this way it will only be available to you and you will be able to do "Package Flights" to deliver your app packages to any person or entity you want.

Comment: I cant add appxbundle to it. Available customizations pane > Runtime settings > UniversalAppInstall > DeviceContextApp. Cant browse to add appxbundle. What is the reason for it? Showing Validation errors: Setting 'UniversalAppInstall/devicecontextapp/packagenamexxx/applicatinfile' must be configured.